# How to fix can't call setState on a component, but it might bug in your application using React Js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I currently new for this framework, I have question regarding on this error. why does this error shows to my console. and the hamburger icon  is shown on top of my navigation bar. I use this https://medium.com/zestgeek/ant-design-navbar-with-responsive-drawer-a8d718e471e0 for my navigation responsive with a drawer. I just follow the codes he inserted on each component, but some of there codes i revise. I hope someone could help me for this.

**Website Output:**

[image]

**Error:**

```
Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the Navigation component.
```

**Navigation Js:**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import LeftMenu from './LeftMenu';
import RightMenu from './RightMenu';
import { Drawer, Button } from 'antd';

class Navigation extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            current: 'mail',
            visible: false
        };
        this.showDrawer = this.showDrawer(this);
        this.onClose = this.onClose(this);
    }

    showDrawer(){
        this.setState({
            visible: true,
        });
    }
    onClose(){
        this.setState({
            visible: false,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="menuBar">
          <div className="logo">
            <a href="">logo</a>
          </div>
          <div className="menuCon">
            <div className="leftMenu">
              <LeftMenu />
            </div>
            <div className="rightMenu">
                <RightMenu />
            </div>
            <Button className="barsMenu" type="primary" onClick={this.showDrawer}>
              <span className="barsBtn"></span>
            </Button>
            <Drawer
              title="Basic Drawer"
              placement="right"
              closable={false}
              onClose={this.onClose}
              visible={this.state.visible}
            >
              <LeftMenu />
              <RightMenu />
            </Drawer>
            </div>
        </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default Navigation;
```

CSS:

```
<style>

.menuBar{
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e8e8e8;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #f3f1f1;
    }
    .logo{
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    }
    .logo a{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 19px 20px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    .menuCon{
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
    float: left;
    }
    .menuCon .ant-menu-item{
    padding: 0px 5px;
    }
    .menuCon .ant-menu-submenu-title{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    }
    .menuCon .ant-menu-item a, .menuCon .ant-menu-submenu-title a{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    }
    .menuCon .ant-menu-horizontal{
    border-bottom: none;
    }
    .menuCon .leftMenu{
    float: left;
    }
    .menuCon .rightMenu{
    float: right;
    }
    .barsMenu{
    float: right;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    display: none;
    background: none;
    }
    .barsBtn{
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #1890ff;
    position: relative;
    }
    .barsBtn:after,.barsBtn:before{
    content: attr(x);
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    left: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #1890ff;
    }
    .barsBtn:after{
    top: auto;
    bottom: -6px;
    }
    .ant-drawer-body{
    padding: 0;
    }
    .ant-drawer-body .ant-menu-horizontal > .ant-menu-item, .ant-drawer-body .ant-menu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .ant-drawer-body .ant-menu-horizontal{
    border-bottom: none;
    }
    .ant-drawer-body .ant-menu-horizontal > .ant-menu-item:hover{
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }

    @media(max-width: 767px){
    .barsMenu{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .leftMenu,.rightMenu{
        display: none;
    }
    .logo a{
        margin-left: -20px;
    }
    .menuCon .ant-menu-item, .menuCon .ant-menu-submenu-title{
        padding: 1px 20px;
    }
    .logo a{
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: In constructor please update ```this.showDrawer = this.showDrawer.bind(this);``` ```this.onClose = this.onClose.bind(this);```

Comment: Can you add a codepen for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use fat arrow for functions for automatic bindings

```
    showDrawer = () => {
        this.setState({
            visible: true,
        });
    }
    onClose = () => {
        this.setState({
            visible: false,
        });
    }
```

and remove the following lines from constructor

```
this.showDrawer = this.showDrawer(this);
this.onClose = this.onClose(this);
```

OR

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            current: 'mail',
            visible: false
        };
        this.showDrawer = this.showDrawer.bind(this);
        this.onClose = this.onClose.bind(this);
    }
```

and if you want hide the button on state change

```
<Button className={`barsMenu {!this.state.visible ? 'hideBarsMenu' : ''`} type="primary" onClick={this.showDrawer}>
  <span className="barsBtn"></span>
</Button>
```

and add a css class

```
.hideBarsMenu {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: if i use that arrow function it shows this .  showDrawer = () => {
     |                ^
  24 |         this.setState({
  25 |             visible: true,
  26 |         });

Comment: it shows this error . rror: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\xampp\htdocs\hfi\resources\js\components\UserNavigation\Navigation.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (23:16):

Comment: Ok may be issue with version you're using, updating the answer :)

Comment: Just update constructor method like mentioned in the answer @DevGe

Comment: I already use that method. but the hamburger icon on top is not hidding.

Comment: take a look on my css code. and showDrawer and closeDrawer function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196613/discussion-between-nagesh-sanika-and-devge).

Answer (score 0):

Please change your constructor as shown below:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            current: 'mail',
            visible: false
        };
        this.showDrawer = this.showDrawer.bind(this);
        this.onClose = this.onClose.bind(this);
    }
```

In your code, when you write this.showDrawer(this) you are actually invling the showDrawer function with this as argument.

Since constructor runs before the component mounts, calling showDrawer function runs code inside it and tries to update state using setState which isn't allowed.